# Usage of * in Batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that I acquired from a public forum, so unfortunately the original author is unknown to me. The batch file is called by a program running on a Windows server.

The purpose of the code is to copy .PDF files, move them to a different folder location on the server, and in the process, dynamically rename the files based upon values from a database.

The five variables declared within the code (%1 %2 %3 %4 %5) are command line arguments that are passed into the batch file. Variables %1 and %3 are basically 'hard-coded' values, while variables %2, %4, and %5 are variable.

The code is fully functional and I've modified it to suit my needs. However, I don't understand one of the statements in the code, so I'm hoping someone might be able to shed a little light on how or why it functions this way.

What I don't understand is the usage of the asterisk in line 23: IF %2==*

Functionally, I know that the end result of this bit of code is that if there is no value populated in the %2 variable, the code sets the file name prefix to nothing, otherwise it sets the prefix to whatever value is in the variable.

I understand the == comparison operator, I'm just not sure about the usage of the asterisk character in this context. I was expecting something like the following code instead: IF %2==""

I poked around on Google for awhile, looking for other examples or a possible explanation, but I couldn't find anything helpful. Can anyone shed any light on this? Thanks in advance!

Here's the code for the batch file:

```
@ECHO off

REM Set global variables
SET OutputFolder=D:\Temp
SET Prefix=

REM %1 Destination sub-folder name 
REM %2 Prefix to add to file name (variable value, can be blank)
REM %3 File extension (set to pdf)
REM %4 Original output file location (full folder path on server)
REM %5 Original file name

ECHO %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 >> D:\Temp\CopyOutputLog.txt
cd %4

:FileExistTest
%~dp0\SLEEP.EXE 1
ECHO Does %5.%3 exist? ...
IF EXIST %4\%5.%3 (GOTO CopyFile) ELSE (GOTO FileExistTest)

:CopyFile
ECHO About to copy %5.%3 ...
IF %2==* (SET Prefix=) ELSE (SET PREFIX=%2)
COPY %4\%5.%3 "%OutputFolder%\%1\%Prefix%%5.%3"
GOTO end

:end
```

Comment: Do not over think it.   Essentially all variables in a batch file are string. The basic function of the `IF` command is to compare `STRINGS`.  So all you are doing is checking if one string is equal to another.  The only exception to this is comparing numbers which you can then use GTR, LSS and other comparison operators for numerics.

Comment: Gotcha...I definitely was overthinking it. So, it looks like the original author of the batch file wanted to exclude the asterisk character, in the unlikely event that a single asterisk character were passed via the database. Otherwise, the resulting PDF file would be named *.pdf, which would obviously be a problem. As Ilya Bursov points out below though, it looks like the code is incomplete, as it would still allow through a number of other special characters that aren't allowed: / \ ? % : | " < > and space.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is [reserved character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) for file names, so to prevent errors if somebody pass it to script - original author discards it.

Unfortunately there are more special symbols, so this code is only partially correct.

Comment: So, you're saying that particular line in the code is looking to see if the value in the %2 variable is literally the asterisk character? Ah, that makes sense. I knew that the asterisk was reserved and is typically used as a wild card that means all, which is why the code wasn't making sense to me.